# Repository in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I have a dbml file that has stored procedures dragged off. I have an `EmployeeModel` class that has `get` and `set` properties.

I have an interface `IEmployee` and an `EmployeeRepository` repository that has the implementation of the methods. Please refer to the code. In the stored procedure `GetRoles` I just have `SELECT * FROM ROLE`.

In the repository, how do I loop through the resultset? Can I change `ISingleResult` to `IMultipleResult` in the dbml designer file?

```
 EmployeeModel.cs:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MvcWebsite.Models
{
    public class EmployeeModel
    {
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public string RoleName { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TaskMark { get; set; }
        public int RoleFlag { get; set; }
    }
}

 IEmployee:

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Text;
  using MvcWebsite.Models;

  namespace MvcWebsite.DAL
  {
    public interface IEmployees
    {
        IList<EmployeeModel> ListAll();
        // void Save(EmployeeModel employ);
    }
  }

  EmployeeRepository.cs:

  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using MvcWebsite.Models;
  using System.Data.Linq;

  namespace MvcWebsite.DAL
  {
    public class EmployeeRepository:IEmployees
    {

        private DataDataContext _dataContext;

        public EmployeeRepository()
        {
            _dataContext = new DataDataContext();
        }


        public IList<EmployeeModel> ListAll()
        {
            //IMultipleResults result =_dataContext.GetRoleDetails();
            //var Emps = result.GetResult(EmployeeModel);
            List<EmployeeModel> emp = _dataContext.GetRoleDetails();
            // foreach (GetRoleDetailsResult role in Emps)
            // {
            // role.Description=Emps.

            // }
            return Emps.ToList();

        }
     }
 }
```

Error:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList'.
>   An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a
>   cast?)    C:\Users\guhananth\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\MVC_SP\MvcWebsite\DAL\EmployeeRepository.cs 44  19  MvcWebsite

Comment: What is Emps in the return statement?

Comment: You should also consider adding pagination to the ListAll method, unless you know that the number of Employees is relatively small and will not increase much.

Answer (score 0):

Typicall you would use:

```
List<EmployeeModel> emp = _dataContext.Employees.ToList();
```

You can read about a Entity Framework implementation of the Repository pattern here: http://blog.gauffin.org/2013/01/repository-pattern-done-right/